# Stack Exchange data explorer does not show all the query results if the result set larger than 50000 .... How can I get all the result?

Tags: discussion

The data explorer of data exchange can view a maximum of 50000 records of the result set. My queries result is larger than 50000 and I want to view whole result set and download the full result.

Comment: cross site dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213050/why-cant-i-pull-in-all-the-so-users-from-data-explorer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the tables in The Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) hold a lot of rows. On the other hand we are able to construct and run almost any thinkable query against that poor Sql Server instance.

There had to be a trade-off between having a reasonable performance for everybody while not bringing the network infrastructure down to its knees when you and many more execute

```
select * from posts
```

In the configuration classes of SEDE you'll find this [setting](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/d3aef79d2695bb3016b4b9892fefc6d0eb308758/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/AppSettings.cs#L24)

```
    [Default(50000)]
    public static int MaxResultsPerResultSet { get; private set; }
```

and when the resultset is prepared to be sent to the [client](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/0167791a559f5ac040ba9c29d5d9bd2b20696638/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/QueryRunner.cs#L396):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     if (++currentRow > AppSettings.MaxResultsPerResultSet || totalRows + currentRow > AppSettings.MaxTotalResults)
     {
          resultSet.Truncated = true;
          break;
     }
```

This makes that you'll never be able to get more then 50,000 rows per resultset returned to the client.

As indicated by [CRABOLO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/crabolo) both myself and  [Normal Human](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/normal-human) provided some possible solutions/hacks to get around that limit a bit as answer on [Why can't I pull in all the SO users from Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213050/why-cant-i-pull-in-all-the-so-users-from-data-explorer) over on Meta Stack Exchange.

Beside those options another alternative you might want to check is the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) but that also limits the number of calls/results.